# How do I print the values that have been increased within an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, program-entry-point

I have this code which is intended to take values of type double from an arraylist and increase them by a percentage amount.

```
public class Company {
static ArrayList<Employee> employees;

public Company() {
    Company.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}


    public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
        Company.employees = employees;
    }

        public void increaseSalaries(double rate) {
            if (rate <= 0.0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            } else {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < employees.size() ; i++) {
                employees.get(i).increaseSalaries(rate);
                }
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Company businesstown = new Company();
        HourlyEmployee george;
        MonthlyEmployee ambrose;
        george = new HourlyEmployee("George", "McClellan", "1537", 1.04);
        ambrose = new MonthlyEmployee("Ambrose", "Burnside", "1536", 741.0);
        businesstown.getEmployees().add(george);
        businesstown.getEmployees().add(ambrose);
        double increase = 20.0;
        System.out.println(businesstown);
        businesstown.increaseSalaries(increase);
        System.out.println(businesstown);

    } 

}
```

I want to print out the objects within the arraylist before and after the increase but I'm unsure how. The current print commands are placeholder as I know they're incorrect. I have tried other methods such as

```
for (Object[] array : list) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

but this hasn't worked. What would work in this instance?

Comment: Oh boy, many many many things wrong with your code. That field should better **not** be static. This way "Company.employees" of addressing the field is super confusing. It is sort of good on the other hand, as it emphasizes "its a static field". But as said: the field should not be static. Then use "List" as type, you only care about ArrayList when you do the `List<Whatever> things = new ArrayList<>()` for example. Then: read a good book. The question how to iterate a Java List is described in any good book/tutorial. No need to *guess* how to do that.

Comment: The other thing: simply implement a reasonable `toString()` method on your Employee class. Then you can just **print** these objects, and you get nice human readable output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for each loop to print out all the contents of an Array:

```
for(Employee e: employees){
    System.out.println(e.getSalary());
}
```

Comment: Employee doesn't have a getter for salary, rather the classes HourlyEmployee and MonthlyEmployee extend Employee, and they have the getters getHourlySalary and getMonthlySalary respectively. How can I implement those?

Comment: Put the Methhod getSalary() in Employee and overwrite them in HourlyEmployee and MonthlyEmployee. Then you can call like shown above. The according Method will be called depending if you have an HourlyEmployee or Monthly Employee. You can put both MonthlyEmployee and HourlyEmployee inside an Array of type Employee. This is called Polymorphism if you want to look into it.

Comment: There is a method within Employee already which calls the getter for each of the extended classes, so I used that. Thanks